# Estimation Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

I aim to show, without computing the integral that

$$\left| \int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2 - 1} \right| \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Where $\gamma$ is the quarter circle from 2 to 2i in the first quadrant.

The length of this path is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so my main issue is showing $$ \left| \frac{1}{z^2 - 1} \right| \leq \frac{2}{3}$$ for all z along the path.

My first step would be to write $z = 2e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \in \left [0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$

My thoughts are, in this interval, a maximum only occurs either at some stationary point or at the endpoints, so $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I would attempt to show that the function has no stationary point in the interval, then since at 0, the function has a local maximum of $\frac{1}{3}$, I could show the integral would be less than or equal to pi/6 which in turn is less than pi/3.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of that path is $\pi$ not $\pi/2$.
Now $|z^2-1|\geq|z^2|-1=3$ so $|\frac{1}{z^2-1}| \leq 1/3$. The result follows